# Passing multiple arguments to parallel function when uploading to FTP

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, ncftp

I'm using `ncftpput` to upload images to a ftp server.
An example of the script is

```bash
#                         destination.       origin
ncftpput -R ftp_server icon_d2/cape_cin ./cape_cin_*.png
ncftpput -R ftp_server icon_d2/t_v_pres ./t_v_pres_*.png
ncftpput -R ftp_server icon_d2/it/cape_cin ./it/cape_cin_*.png
ncftpput -R ftp_server icon_d2/it/t_v_pres ./it/t_v_pres_*.png
```

I'm trying to parallelize this with GNU `parallel` but I'm struggling to pass the arguments to `ncftpput`. I know what I'm doing wrong but somehow can not find the solution.

If I construct the array of what I need to upload

```bash
images_output=("cape_cin" "t_v_pres")

# suffix for naming
projections_output=("" "it/")
# remote folder on server
projections_output_folder=("icon_d2" "icon_d2/it")

# Create a list of all the images to upload 
upload_elements=()
for i in "${!projections_output[@]}"; do
    for j in "${images_output[@]}"; do
        upload_elements+=("${projections_output_folder[$i]}/${j} ./${projections_output[$i]}${j}_*.png")
    done
done
```

Then I can do the upload in serial like this

```bash
for k in "${upload_elements[@]}"; do
   ncftpput -R ftp_server ${k}
done
```

When using `parallel` I'm using `colsep` to separate the arguments

```bash
parallel -j 5 --colsep ' ' ncftpput -R ftp_server ::: "${upload_elements[@]}"
```

but `ncftpput` gives an error that tells me it is not understanding the structure of the passed argument.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parallel -j 5 --colsep ' ' eval ncftpput -R ftp_server ::: "${upload_elements[@]}"
```

This should do exactly the same:

```
for k in "${upload_elements[@]}"; do
   echo ncftpput -R ftp_server ${k}
done | parallel -j 5
```

Comment: hey, unfortunately this still has the same issue :(